# Javascript How to Get Accurate Count of Characters in Textarea Form Field

Tags: javascript

I've been searching Google and threads for a How To for this, but not finding what I need.  I'm using JS to do a little character count-down on textarea fields in a form. How I do it is pretty standard and it works, until I try to use the data that is submitted.

My Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#available_days_times').keyup( function(){
    showLength( $('#available_days_times'), $('#available_days_times_label'), 1000 );
  });
  ...
});


function showLength(field_id, label_id, maxLength){
    var currentLength = field_id.val().length;
    var charactersLeft = maxLength - currentLength;

    label_id.addClass("red");
    if( currentLength >= maxLength ) {
        charactersLeft = 0;
        field_id.val( field_id.val().substring(0, maxLength-1) )
    }
    label_id.text("Characters allowed: " + maxLength + " You have " + charactersLeft + " characters left");
}
```

This works fine, until I copy-paste text (below) that has over 1000 characters. The code is truncating it to 1000 characters, but I get a size error when submitting the form data into a database table. The maxLength equals the size of the db table.column for that field.

Here is an example of text with I used for testing:

```
sunday = n/a
monday = 8:00am to 4:00pm
wednesday = 8:00am to 5:00pm
friday = 12:00pm to 5:00pm
saturday = 5:00pm to 9:00pm
sunday = n/a
monday = 8:00am to 4:00pm
wednesday = 8:00am to 5:00pm
friday = 12:00pm to 5:00pm
saturday = 5:00pm to 9:00pm
sunday = n/a
monday = 8:00am to 4:00pm
wednesday = 8:00am to 5:00pm
friday = 12:00pm to 5:00pm
saturday = 5:00pm to 9:00pm
sunday = n/a
monday = 8:00am to 4:00pm
wednesday = 8:00am to 5:00pm
friday = 12:00pm to 5:00pm
saturday = 5:00pm to 9:00pm
sunday = n/a
monday = 8:00am to 4:00pm
wednesday = 8:00am to 5:00pm
friday = 12:00pm to 5:00pm
saturday = 5:00pm to 9:00pm
sunday = n/a
monday = 8:00am to 4:00pm
wednesday = 8:00am to 5:00pm
friday = 12:00pm to 5:00pm
saturday = 5:00pm to 9:00pm
sunday = n/a
monday = 8:00am to 4:00pm
wednesday = 8:00am to 5:00pm
friday = 12:00pm to 5:00pm
saturday = 5:00pm to 9:00pm
sunday = n/a
monday = 8:00am to 4:00pm
wednesday = 8:00am to 5:00pm
friday = 12:00pm to 5:00pm
saturday = 5:00pm to 9:00pm
sunday = n/a
mond
```

If I copy-paste that into my form's textarea, javascript sees it as 999 characters, but my database sees it as 1038 and throws a fit.

Since there are no really odd characters, I'm thinking that javascript is not counting the returns as two characters. There are about 40 lines and that about matches the difference between 999 and 1038.

Is there a way, using JavaScript to get an accurate count of characters that would match the count the db sees?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I shall give that a try.  Thank you for sharing that. It is one I did not find in my Google travels

Comment: @HereticMonkey  That works!!! Thank you so much for pointing me to that.